# RAILS: db count is always 0 in spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Here is a simple case of spec in Rails 4.2:

```
it "returns redirect to Save & Copy" do
        user_access = FactoryGirl.create(:user_access, :action => 'create', :resource =>'simple_orderx_orders', :role_definition_id => @role.id, :rank => 1,
        :sql_code => "")
        session[:user_id] = @u.id
        q1 = FactoryGirl.create(:simple_orderx_order)
        q = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:simple_orderx_order)
        FactoryGirl.create(:project_misc_definitionx_misc_definition, :resource_id => q1.id, :resource_string => 'simple_orderx_orders', definition_category: 'production_step')
        expect {
        get 'create', {:order => q, commit: I18n.t('Save & Copy')}     
        expect(response).to redirect_to URI.escape(SUBURI + "/view_handler?index=0&msg=Successfully Saved!")
        }.to change(ProjectMiscDefinitionx::MiscDefinition.all.reload, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
```

In debugger, there is a new record being added to table `MiscDefinition` and `MiscDefinition.all.count` is `2`, but in spec the `ProjectMiscDefinitinox::MiscDefinition.all.count` is always `0` and the spec case fails. What could cause the counting error in spec?

Here is the `create` in controller:

```
def create
      @order = SimpleOrderx::Order.new(new_params)
      @order.last_updated_by_id = session[:user_id]
      @order.entered_by_id = session[:user_id]
      @order.fort_token = session[:fort_token]
      copy_steps(@order) if params[:commit] == I18n.t('Save & Copy')  #copy mfg steps from previous  order
      if @order.save
        copy_steps(@order.reload) if params[:commit] == I18n.t('Save & Copy')  #copy mfg steps from previous  order
        redirect_to URI.escape(SUBURI + "/view_handler?index=0&msg=Successfully Saved!")
      else
        @erb_code = find_config_const('order_new_view', session[:fort_token], 'simple_orderx')
        flash[:notice] = t('Data Error. Not Saved!')
        render 'new'
      end
    end

def copy_steps(order)
      obj = Order.where('drawing_num = ? AND id != ?', order.drawing_num, order.id).order('created_at DESC') if order.drawing_num.present? #find the previous order of the same drawing#
      obj = Order.where('part_num = ? AND id != ?', order.part_num, order.id).order('created_at DESC') if obj.blank? && order.part_num.present?
      obj = Order.where('part_name Like ? AND id != ?', "%#{order.part_name}%", order.id).order('created_at DESC') if obj.blank? && order.part_name.present?
      copied = false
      obj.limit(4).each do |o|
        SimpleOrderx.production_step_class.where('resource_id = ? AND resource_string = ? AND definition_category = ?', o.id, params[:controller].sub('/', '_'), 'production_step').each do |r|
          new_step = SimpleOrderx.production_step_class.new()
          new_step = r.dup
          new_step.resource_id = order.id
          begin
            new_step.save
            copied = true
          rescue => e
            flash[:notice] = 'Error in copying production steps: ' + e.message
          end    
        end 
        return if copied
      end if obj.present?
    end
```

Comment: It is really hard to tell without knowing what you are doing in the controller ...

Comment: here is the controller code. The method `copy_steps` is to save a new record in `MiscDefinition`

Comment: If I were you I would check if `new_step.save` actually wrote to the database. Chance is that `.save` does not raise exception, instead it returns false when validation failed, so your code executed through without catching the error. To make it raise an exception on validation failed, call `.save!` instead

Comment: Yes, in debugger `new_step.save` wrote to the table and adds a new record (count returns 2). I can not think of a reason why `count` always return `0` in spec. It seems that the db connection in spec is never updated.

Comment: Can you try simplifying the change clause and test it again: `... to change(ProjectMiscDefinitionx::MiscDefinition.count).by(1)` You don't need to do `all.reload` since class methods will make a new query. `reload` is only needed if you already have an initialized object of a record, and the DB entry of that record has changed since

Comment: `KKulikovskis`, there is no difference, with or without `all.reload`.